GNS3 on Raspberry Pi 5
I want to install GNS3 on my new raspberry Pi 5 with 8 GB RAM. I am running ubuntu desktop in it and having issues in installation GNS3 I tried many things by Google search but nothing works.
If there is any way to install GNS3 on Raspberry Pi 5 8 GB RAM, please explain it weather it require another OS or any thing.

Welcome -- but saying "I tried many things" but not what any of them were and asking for help invites other people to waste their time making suggestions you have already heard.  It also begs to question that you did these things correctly in the first place when we have no evidence of that. Please make an effort to explain in detail everything you have tried and what went wrong when tried them, and edit these details into the question, do not simply post them as comments.  Also please take the tour to understand better how the site works.

having issues in installation doesn't really mean anything ... it's like going to a doctor with a broken finger and saying I'm feeling discomfort when asked what the problem is
